# In T-SQL is it possible to have numbers in a table to have a different display name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I am wondering if it is possible in T-SQL to give a "display" name or something to a number for reporting reasons. For example, I have a table like this:

```
SELECT  [IDNumber]
      ,[Name]
      ,[Status]
      ,[CurrentStep]
      ,[Exceptions]
      ,[ItemCount]
  FROM [Batch].[dbo].[BatchNa]
```

My current step has multiple numbers:

- -1 = Complete
- 1 = Start
- 2 = Create
- 3 = Check
- 4 = Verify
- 5 = Double Blind
- 6 = etc

And so forth.

When I spit out a table report I get this spit out:

```
123 | Test | In Progress | 3 | No | 512
```

Any advice on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a table that maps between the numeric step and the display name and join on it:

```sql
SELECT  [IDNumber]
      ,[Name]
      ,[Status]
      ,[DisplayName]
      ,[Exceptions]
      ,[ItemCount]
  FROM [Batch].[dbo].[BatchNa] b
  JOIN [Batch].[dbo].[Steps] s ON b.[CurerntStep] = s.[Step]
```

Comment: Adding that the `BatchNa` should have a foreign key to the `Steps` table. This will ensure only valid `CurrentStep` values can be inserted and correct query results.

Comment: That doesn't protect from missing entries in `Steps` though, so I would make it a left join to make sure actual data is not lost when there is no description.

Answer (score 2):

You need new table or temprory table like this :

Example :

```
DECLARE @TBL_STATUSCODE TABLE (CODE NVARCHAR(50) , DESCRIPTION NVARCHAR(250))
INSERT INTO @TBL_STATUSCODE (CODE , DESCRIPTION)
SELECT '-1'  , 'Complete'
UNION
SELECT '0'  , 'Start'
UNION
SELECT '2'  , 'Create'
UNION
SELECT '3'  , 'Check'


SELECT  BN.[IDNumber]
      ,BN.[Name]
      ,BN.[Status]
      ,BN.[CurrentStep]
      ,BN.[Exceptions]
      ,BN.[ItemCount]
      ,TBL.DESCRIPTION AS DisplayName
  FROM [Batch].[dbo].[BatchNa] BN 
  LEFT JOIN @TBL_STATUSCODE TBL ON BN.[Status] = TBL.CODE
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a dirty way to handle this too! I like some of the solutions above and am going to play with it!

````
      WHEN [CurrentStep] = 1 THEN 'Scan'
      WHEN [CurrentStep] = 2 THEN 'Quality Assurance'
      WHEN [CurrentStep] = 3 THEN 'Wide Format Import'
      WHEN [CurrentStep] = 4 THEN 'Classification'
      WHEN [CurrentStep] = 5 THEN 'Index'
      WHEN [CurrentStep] = 6 THEN 'Data Verification'
      WHEN [CurrentStep] = 7 THEN 'Supervisor Review'
      WHEN [CurrentStep] = 8 THEN 'OCR'
      WHEN [CurrentStep] = 9 THEN 'PSI Migration'
      WHEN [CurrentStep] = 10 THEN 'SQL Migration'
      END AS WorkflowStepName```
````

Comment: If you are going to do it this way, then see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-choose-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: You could use a _simple case_ rather than a _searched case_: `case CurrentStep when 1 then 'Scan' when 2 then 'QA' ... else 'n/a' end`. Ref: [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 1):

Just because I did not see `CHOOSE()` mentioned.

A LEFT JOIN to a mapping table would be my first choice (+1 Mureinik)

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (CurrentStep int)
Insert into @YourTable values
(1),(2)

Select *
      ,Stat = isnull(choose(CurrentStep,'Scan','Quality Assurance','Wide Format Import','Classification','Index','Data Verification','Supervisor Review','OCR','PSI Migration','SQL Migration'),'Undefined')
 From  @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
CurrentStep Stat
1           Scan
2           Quality Assurance
```